# What is the maximum range of varchar in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, varchar, sqldatatypes

What is the maximum range of varchar in MySQL?

I am using the latest version of MySQL and in many sites it is being told that the size is 255. But when i am trying to give a higher size like 500 or 1000, it works for me. So is there a maximum number for varchar datatype?

Comment: 255 is the largest VARCHAR size that can be indexed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was 255 before 5.0.3, [but now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to **65,535**.

[The documentation of 5.0.x](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) shows the transition:

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Comment: Then the size is same as that of text data type i guess.
Text range is also 65,535

Comment: I got it :)
The most important thing is "The length is shared amont all column", which is not in the case of text data type. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

> The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html

Answer (score 2):

From [the specs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html)

> Values in VARCHAR columns are
>   variable-length strings. The length
>   can be specified as a value from 0 to
>   65,535. The effective maximum length
>   of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum
>   row size (65,535 bytes, which is
>   shared among all columns) and the
>   character set used.