# Why does MySQL allow VARCHAR(255) to have larger numbers

Tags: php, mysql

When I first learnt about field types in MySQL I would define anything that was not a number as a VARCHAR and set the length to anything. 500 2000, but am I right in saying the maximum is actually 255?

If this is the case, why does MySQL let me define columns with much larger lengths and what is it actually doing? Will it allow larger lengths? Does it define the column / field as something else?

Any advice welcomed.

Comment: *Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was changed after 5.0.3:

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. **The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to
>   65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.** The effective maximum length of a
>   VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size
>   (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character
>   set used.

From [The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is 65k

[The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

It was 255 before 5.0.3, [but now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html):

```
    Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be
 specified as a value from 0 to 65,535.
```

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) of 5.0.x shows the transition:

```
Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be
specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535
in 5.0.3 and later versions.
```

ref: [What is the maximum range of varchar in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907467/what-is-the-maximum-range-of-varchar-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `varchar(n)` with values of n up to 255 and values larger than 255.

MySQL stores variable length strings by encoding the length of the string in the first one or two bytes.  For values less than 256, MySQL uses one byte of overhead for the length.  For values of n as 256 or greater, MySQL uses two bytes of overhead for the length.

Note that this is based on the *definition* of the column, not on the contents.  So an empty string (`''`) could occupy 1 byte as a `varchar(255)` and 2 bytes as a `varchar(256)` (not counting space for storing `NULL` flags).

To refresh your member, one byte can store integers from 0 to 255, and two bytes can store from 0 to 65,535.  This is where these limits come from.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL explanation, click on the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) for further information.

> A VARCHAR(255) column can hold a string with a maximum length of 255 characters. Assuming that the column uses the latin1 character set (one byte per character), the actual storage required is the length of the string (L), plus one byte to record the length of the string. For the string 'abcd', L is 4 and the storage requirement is five bytes. If the same column is instead declared to use the ucs2 double-byte character set, the storage requirement is 10 bytes: The length of 'abcd' is eight bytes and the column requires two bytes to store lengths because the maximum length is greater than 255 (up to 510 bytes).